# Finding the first occurence of 1-digit number in a list in Raku

Tags: list, raku

I've got a number of lists of various lengths. Each of the lists starts with some numbers which are multiple digits but ends up with a recurring 1-digit number. For instance:

```
my @d = <751932 512775 64440 59994 9992 3799 423 2 2 2 2>;
my @e = <3750 3177 4536 4545 686 3 3 3>;
```

I'd like to find the position of the first occurence of the 1-digit number (for `@d` 7 and for `@e` 5) without constructing any loop.  Ideally a lambda (or any other practical thing) should iterate over the list using a condition such as `$_.chars == 1` and as soon as the condition is fulfilled it should stop and return the position. Instead of returing the position, it might as well return the list up until the 1-digit number; changes and improvisations are welcome. How to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want the `:k` modifier on `first`:

```
say @d.first( *.chars == 1, :k ) # 7
say @e.first( *.chars == 1, :k ) # 5
```

See [first](https://docs.raku.org/type/Any#routine_first) for more information.

To answer your second part of the question:

```
say @d[^$_] with @d.first( *.chars == 1, :k );
# (751932 512775 64440 59994 9992 3799 423)
say @e[^$_] with @e.first( *.chars == 1, :k );
# (3750 3177 4536 4545 686)
```

Make sure that you use the `with` to ensure you only show the slice if `first` actually found an entry.

See [with](https://docs.raku.org/language/control#index-entry-control_flow_with) for more information.